# Understanding IP address assignment and routing of hosted network

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, netsh, internet-sharing

The hosted network ("Wifi tethering" or "wireless access point") can be enabled with:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=[name] key=[password]
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

So far, so good.

However, the following things are completely unclear to me (and nowhere to be found):

1. Is the hosted network adapter supposed to have an IP address (non 169.x) or not? **If no**, how is it supposed to be used? (of course, I can statically assign an IP to an interface but ideally this would happen automatically without generating collisions). **If yes** what is the exact mechanism (service etc.) that assigns the IP address?
2. How do wireless clients obtain IP addresses? There must be a DHCP service of some sort. What is the exact mechanism?
3. How exactly does the routing work between the wireless clients and the internet interface? As usual, I can manually execute a route command but there must be a mechanism that configures this properly. How?

The reason that I ask these questions:

- When I execute `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`, the "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter" adapter (most of the time, not always!) has 169.254.74.242 assigned. In my opinion, this is wrong and should be 192.168.137.1. I want to debug what the heck is going wrong.
- When wireless clients connect they do not get an IP address assigned. I want to debug what the heck is going on. (e.g., is a DHCP service dead or so?)
- When I assign all IP addresses manually, I can ping the wireless clients and the wireless clients ping the host computer but they still cannot access the internet, although the internet connection is shared. I want to debug what the heck is going on where (e.g., which route entries, if any, should I expect to see, which firewall rules etc.)

I have tried restarting Windows, restarting SharedAccess service, stopping and starting hostednetwork. Even deleting the hosted network interface from the device manager.

Answer (score 1):

I think Windows' built-in "Internet Connection Sharing" feature should handle all of this for you, so just use that, unless the real intent behind the question boils down to "How do I manually use the command line to set up all the things Internet Connection Sharing would have set up for me automatically?".

Some background info may help here, to clear up possible misconceptions.

[By the way, you didn't say what your existing Internet-connected interface is, so for convenience' sake I'm going to assume it is an Ethernet NIC connected to an existing Ethernet LAN that already has a DHCP server and an IP router on it.]

Wi-Fi is a layer 2 technology like Ethernet. It's independent of layer 3 technologies like IP. Wi-Fi, by design, doesn't really know anything about IP. The interface doesn't need an IP address, nor does it need to serve out IP addresses via DHCP or anything else, nor does it need to do IP routing.

For example, you could just enable layer 2 bridging between your Wi-Fi interface and your Ethernet interface, so that your wireless clients are just transparently connected to your existing Ethernet LAN. That way wireless clients could get IP address leases via DHCP from your existing DHCP server on your Ethernet LAN, and they'd all be on the same subnet with the rest of your LAN, so that service discovery protocols work.

If you want to enable IP forwarding (basic IP routing) or NAT (NAPT) gatewaying between Wi-Fi and Ethernet, you can. If you do that, you'll probably want to manually give the Wi-Fi interface an IP address on a different subnet than your existing Ethernet LAN. You'll probably want to use an RFC 1918 private subnet that's not already in use on your home network or on any other private network you ever VPN into. You may also want to enable DHCP service on the Wi-Fi interface to serve out other addresses on that new subnet to any wireless clients that join the network.

Comment: I see, thanks! So everything is inside the SharedAccess service? I think I have to re-phrase my question a bit. The reason I am asking is that this piece of *** is not doing what I expect and nowhere details are found how to debug or what should even be the expected state. Maybe you know a little bit more details. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clear info about the "hostednetwork" feature in Windows. In your answer I see this phrase: "you could just enable layer 2 bridging between your Wi-Fi interface and your Ethernet interface..."
That's exactly what I'ld like to do, but I don't know how to manage this in Windows (10). I have on my laptop Ethernet LAN access to the internet, but also to a NAS on my LAN. How can I bridge my LAN to WiFi, so my mobile phone is able to connect -through my laptop- to the LAN, using WiFi (direct)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139018)